# Conditionally route incoming request to preferred ip address, when a single domain is mapped to a group of ip addresses

Tags: nginx

Let's say a domain is mapped to multiple ip addresses. Typically, each incoming request is served in a round robin fashion among but I want to be able to conditionally route each request to a particular ip address based on the url parameters as shown in below screenshot. Is it possible to do this with nginx or any other tool ?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HHuC.png)

Comment: Just use a `location`.

Comment: could you elaborate or point me to a blogpost. thanks for your response.

Comment: You tagged this post `nginx`. The directive [`location`](https://nginx.org/r/location) is a pretty basic thing that you should have seen on day one. Use one for each URL path.

Comment: I'm familiar with location directive. However, I've only used it with ip addresses that don't share a common domain. So you are saying we can use location for ip addresses that share the same domain. I'll test it out and confirm. thank you.

Comment: `location` has nothing to do with IP addresses or domain names, it matches the URL path only, which is what is shown in your screenshot.

Comment: Do you mean multiple A RRs in the DNS for a given name? Then on each of these addresses a web server must reply and any of these servers may receive any request (even if previous request from the same client was received by another server). You can't control which one gets a request if it's using a shared hostname.